# Infinite process balls in bins problem

Tags: balls-in-bins

Given $n$ balls and $m$ bins, let us consider an infinite process, where in each time slot we throw a ball at a random bin. When all $n$ balls are thrown, we take the balls from the bin with the maximum load, and throw them to random bins until all $n$ balls are thrown and we repeat the process.

What the expected number of balls in the bin with the maximum load is converges to?

A variation of the problem is described in https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~azar/box.pdf, where instead of taken  the bin with the maximum load, a random ball is  selected at random.

In addition, by my experiments, it seems that for $n=\Theta(m)$ the bin with the maximum load converges $2n/m+$ balls. I am trying to prove  it.

Comment: If I understood, at each cycle you are taking the maximum filled (one of the max. ?) bin, empty it, put back in place and restart throwing the balls for the next cycle. Please clarify better the procedure.

Comment: This is exactly what I have meant. I have clarify the question.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it has been [answered](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42339/infinite-process-balls-in-bins-problem) on [cstheory,se].